# JavaScript: Implement 'element.hasAttribute' if undefined [for IE7]

Tags: javascript, html, dom, internet-explorer-7, extend

I need to make an exisitng web application compatible with IE7.

The code uses `element.hasAttribute` extensively and IE7 has issues with this method.

> Object doesn't support property or method 'hasattribute'

I am trying to check in the code if an `input` element has the `hasAttribute` method defined and if not, I am trying to add it to all `input` elements.

```
//create an input element variable << works fine
var myInput = document.createElement("input");

//see if it has the 'hasAttribute' method << condition works fine
if (('hasAttribute' in myInput)==false)
{

    //get all input elements into objInputElements <<works fine
    var objInputElements=document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    // MORE CODE NEEDED - To implement a hasAttribute function for all 
    // elements in the array probably using something
    // like: !!element[attributeName] which works in IE7. See link and notes below.
}
```

[This article](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10131/will-this-test-to-check-if-an-element-has-an-attribute-work) describes how to define a seperate function to do this. However, I would like to add the `hasattribute` method to the elements if it is not defined. (this way I don't need to change all the code that is currently written)

IMPORTANT NOTE: There are > 1000 hidden input fields in the form therefore, the 'hasattribute' method needs to be added to the elements in a very efficient way.

Please let me know the how I could achieve this. Thank you!

Comment: loop over `node.attributes` or check `getAttribute` against `null`.

Comment: You could try `if(!Element.prototype.hasAttribute) Element.prototype.hasAttribute = function() { ...` Not sure how IE7 will react to that.

Comment: @bfavaretto, no support for Element.prototype in IE7

Comment: `node.attributes` is also not supported in IE7. `getAttribute` returns an empty string instead of null per the older DOM3 spec and per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute some DOM implementations (but not IE)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `Element.prototype` is not supported IE < 8, there is no efficient way to polyfill `hasAttribute`. The inefficient way (if you wanted to avoid shimming) would be something like this (placed after all inputs had loaded):

```
<input data-abc="" />
<script>

if (!window.Element || !window.Element.prototype || !window.Element.prototype.hasAttribute) {

(function () {
    function hasAttribute (attrName) {
        return typeof this[attrName] !== 'undefined'; // You may also be able to check getAttribute() against null, though it is possible this could cause problems for any older browsers (if any) which followed the old DOM3 way of returning the empty string for an empty string (yet did not possess hasAttribute as per our checks above). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute
    }
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].hasAttribute = hasAttribute;
    }
}());

}

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
document.write(
    'has?' + inputs[0].hasAttribute('abc') // false
);
document.write(
    'has?' + inputs[0].hasAttribute('data-abc') // true
);

</script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be better as `return this.getAttributeNode(attrName).specified;`  ?

Comment: Well, I found one problem: `getAttributeNode` returns null for non-existent non-DOM attributes, so it would have to be `var an = this.getAttributeNode(attrName); return (an === null) ? false :  an.specified;`

Comment: `getAttributeNode` was not supported until IE 8, so it wouldn't help here. FTR, "specified" was really intended for distinguishing in XML between those attributes which were fixed or made as defaults in an associated DTD and those which were set explicitly in the document; this is not useful for HTML5 which does not rely on DTDs, XML wasn't fully implemented on the web anyways, and `getAttributeNode` itself is deprecated now anyways: http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-element-getattributenode .

Comment: You could just use `getAttribute`, especially since it is no longer spec'd to return the empty string when empty (and IE apparently never followed the old spec anyways), so it will return `null` and thus one can distinguish missing from empty.

Comment: my page running on IE7 works with getAttributeNode, and it is defined as native code. Microsoft says it was introduced in IE6:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536430(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how getAttributeNode being deprecated matters when attempting to create IE7 compatiblity. The problem with `getAttribute` is that it always returns a value in IE7 even when the attribute isn't there which is what .specified will differentiate, and it doesn't use the regular attribute names for attributes that conflict with other javascript properties (e.g. className instead of class).

Comment: My apologies, I just quickly read its notes saying "IE 8 or later". And you're right being deprecated doesn't really matter, except for being annoying if linting programs may alert one about this. IE7 will return a non-null value when the attribute isn't there?

Comment: In some case, yes e.g. `i.getAttribute("maxlength")` on an `<input>` tag in `i` will return a value (not null) even if the attribute isn't present.

Comment: I found that using document.getElementById("elementid")[attrName] works fine on it's own as a replacement for has Attribute, returning true or false, and no requirement to regulate page loading.

Answer (score 0):

I known this is an old post and maybe nobody else use IE7 but if like me you need it (and need to use ajax or something like that) this is my propose.

Maybe we can improve the performance creating a proxy of  `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementById` to do the trick, and this add support to dynamic elements that are created in runtime.

Maybe something like this:

```
if (!window.Element || !window.Element.prototype || !window.Element.prototype.hasAttribute) {
   (function (document) {
      var originalGetElementById = document.getElementById;
      var originalGetElementsByTagName = document.getElementsByTagName;

      // The HasAttribute function.
      function hasAttribute (attrName) {
         return typeof this[attrName] !== 'undefined';
      }

      // Add the HasAttribute to the element if is not present yet.
      function attachFunction (element) {
         if (element && !element.hasAttribute) {
            element.hasAttribute = hasAttribute;
         }
         return element;
      }

      // Proxy of the document.getElementById
      document.getElementById = function (elementId) {
         var element = originalGetElementById(elementId);
         return attachFunction(element);
      }

      // Proxy of the document.getElementsByTagName
      document.originalGetElementsByTagName = function (tagName) {
         var elements = originalGetElementsByTagName(tagName);
         for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
            attachFunction(element[i]);
         }
         return elements;
      }
   }(document));
}
```

And this functionality can be in a separated javascript file included with conditional tags in IE:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="ie7fixs.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<![endif]-->
```

And then just use the `document.getElementsByTagName` or `document.getElementById`.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
document.write(
    'has?' + inputs[0].hasAttribute('abc') // false
);
document.write(
    'has?' + inputs[0].hasAttribute('data-abc') // true
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
//if  po is object then for IE:
if (!po.hasAttribute) po.hasAttribute=function(attr) {
  return this.getAttribute(attr)!=null
};
```